# How to add TXT record in route 53 without domain name in end

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone for eg. "example.com". I want to add a txt record with name "@" sign only. But in route 53 while creating a new record set it defaults come with the domain name in the end.

So, It adds a new record set with "@.example.com" rather than just "@" as a name.

Is it possible to add just "@" or is that "@" resolves to "@.example.com" on backend of creating a new record.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Route 53 doesn't treat @ as special character.  What you will want to do is remove the @ character and leave the name value empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I skimmed through amazon docs not able to find it. Do you know where is the information given?.

Comment: I don't know if it's documented, I found out about it here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=440935&#440935

Comment: do I need to remove "" from value?